# Groovy plugin for Artifactory to restrict move from one Repo to particular repo

Tags: groovy, artifactory

I have 3 repo's in my Artifactory and want to handle the movement of Artifacts through plugin.

```
1. Build-repo
2. Testing-repo
3. Prod-repo
```

Trying to create a plugin to allow Move of Artifact from one Repo `(Build-repo)` to other repo `(Testing-repo)` only. I should stop developers to move directly from `Build-repo` to `Prod-repo`

Similarly `Testing-repo -> Prod-repo`

```
 beforeMove { item, targetRepoPath, properties ->
        log.debug("ENTER storage -> beforeMove")
        if (!security.isAdmin() && item.repoKey.equals("Build-repo")) {
        if (item.targetRepoKey.equals("Prod-repo")) {
                    throw new CancelException("Artifact Move not permitted for ${item.repoKey}: ", 403)
            }
    }
        log.debug("EXIT storage -> beforeMove")
```

But I get a error, This could just be a issue with the usage of Property.  How do I get the complete list of Properties for using groovy plugin.

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: targetRepoKey for class: org.artifactory.model.xstream.fs.FileInfoImpl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property the error refers to is not Artifactory property, but Groovy object property. In line 4 you have `item.targetRepoKey`, while it should be `item.repoKey`.

I strongly recommend you using a proper IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and using trypes in your code e.g. line 1 should be:

`beforeMove { FileInfo item, RepoPath taretRepoPath, Properties properties ->`

That can save you time struggling with such errors.